# Trying to understand CMTime and CMTimeMake

Tags: video, ios4

1) `CMTimeMake(1,10)` means duration of 1 second and timescale of 10, or 10 frames per second. This means 1s duration of video with 10 frames?

2)

```
CMTime lastTime=CMTimeMake(1,10);
CMTime frameTime=CMTimeMake(1, 10);
CMTime currentTime=CMTimeAdd(lastTime, frameTime)
```

= (2, 10) ?

2 seconds of video and with 10 frames per second of the currentTime?

Comment: if your video is 48 FPS (frame per second) then you would easily do `CMTimeMake(1, 48)` to run a block of code every 1/48 of a second ie 1 block per frame

Answer (score 189):

1) `CMTimeMake(1,10)` actually means a value of 1 and a timescale of 10.  They are a numerator and denominator, so it is 1/10 of a second, not 1 second.

2) The result will be like `CMTimeMake(2, 10)`, which is 2/10ths of a second.

Comment: Why apple's reference don't say this?

Comment: Now it says: `value/timescale = seconds` explicitly.

Answer (score 153):

Peter is right.
The following code makes the concept more clear:

1)

```
Float64 seconds = 5; 
int32_t preferredTimeScale = 600;
CMTime inTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds, preferredTimeScale);
CMTimeShow(inTime);
```

The above code gives:
{3000/600 = 5.000}

Which means a total duration of 5 seconds, with 3000 frames with a timescale of 600 frames per second.

2)

```
int64_t value = 10000;
int32_t preferredTimeScale = 600;
CMTime inTime = CMTimeMake(value, preferredTimeScale);
CMTimeShow(inTime);
```

This one gives {10000/600 = 16.667}

Which means a total duration of 16.667 seconds, with 10000 frames with a timescale of 600 frames per second.

Notice the difference between CMTimeMake(int64_t value, int32_t timescale)
and CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64 seconds, int32_t preferredTimeScale)

Hope this explanation helps. For further clarifications, please don't hesitate to post further questions on this post.

Comment: I wonder why `setMaxRecordedDuration` needs the `preferredTimeScale` when `frame_rate` is set differently. Everyone is just blindly using 600, and no good explanation as to exactly what it is doing.

Comment: @dashesy 600 is a multiple of the common video frame rates. Warren Moore explains it at http://warrenmoore.net/understanding-cmtime pretty well.

Answer (score 42):

With `CMTimeMake(A, B)` you store a rational number, an exact fraction `A / B` seconds

- `CMTimeMake(1, 4)` -> the time interval 0.25 seconds

With `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(A, B)` you store `A` *seconds* to a resolution of `B` steps

- `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.25, ...)` -> the time interval 0.25 seconds

You commonly see `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(time, NSEC_PER_SEC)`. The `NSEC_PER_SEC` effectively means "*max resolution*".

Answer (score 12):

## Interval for 1 Second

If you only want to know how to make an interval for **1 second** (like me), this is your answer:

```
int seconds = 1;

CMTime interval = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds, NSEC_PER_SEC);
```

Answer (score 3):

A CMTime struct represents a `length of time that is stored as rational number.` CMTime has a value and a timescale field, and represents the time value/timescale seconds .

See [See this SO Answer which is clear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13001917/2419589)