# How to addd user value to CMTimeMakeWithSecondValue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cmtime

Stop motion app

Trying to get frame duration (/.5)set by users value received from a stepper:  `self.stepperValue;`

Original settings hard coded value of five frames a second

```
// 5 fps - taking 5 pictures will equal 1 second of video
frameDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1./5., 90000);
```

Now trying with frames per second determined by stepper value, What I've tried so far (stepperValue is being read correctly)

```
 int x = self.stepperValue;
 frameDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1./x, 90000);
```

This results on nothing being captured

second attempt

```
 float a = ([_stepperValue.text floatValue]);


// 5 fps - taking 5 pictures will equal 1 second of video
frameDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1./a, 90000);
```

This results in a standard 5 frames per second value no matter value is entered form the stepper

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001755/trying-to-understand-cmtime-and-cmtimemake) may be helpful

Comment: Already checked that out it explains about `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds` but not how to add float values, int values etc to the mix, unless ive missed something will re visit

Comment: Ok revisited the link thanks to your comment and float64 seems to  be trick here.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this

```
 Float64 seconds = ([_stepperValue.text floatValue]);

 frameDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1./seconds, 90000);
```