# Take the thumbnail image at specified using AVAssetImageGenerator

Tags: ios, avasset, cmtime, avassetimagegenerator

I was taking thumbnail image using `AVAssetImageGenerator` by specifying `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds` as  (0.0, 600). It's working fine but I didn't understand the `CMTime`. I read the documentation but it's still not clear. Suppose I want to take the thumbnail image after 5 seconds or exactly/nearest to 5 seconds. Please explain how to set it. What is the difference between these two:

```
CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, 600)
CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(30, 30)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001755/trying-to-understand-cmtime-and-cmtimemake ?

Comment: Hey Larme, thanks for quick reply, the link you posted was very helpful

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't read all my link, but either your question is a duplicate, either you can write a answer to your particular question.