# preferredTimescale in CMTimeMakeWithSeconds

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, cmtime

I am implementing custom camera and for that I want to set exposure duration.

My code for setting slider's properties is-

```
slider.maximumValue = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(camera.activeFormat.maxExposureDuration))
slider.minimumValue = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(camera.activeFormat.minExposureDuration))
```

Now the problem comes while setting the exposure time whenever the slider is changed.

My code for that looks like this -

```
change(duration: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Double(slider.value), 600), iso: AVCaptureISOCurrent)
```

But in

```
func CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(_ seconds: Float64, _ preferredTimescale: Int32) -> CMTime
```

I am confused with `preferredTimescale`, and what should be its value, it's working fine with 600, but what is ideal value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should view the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001755/trying-to-understand-cmtime-and-cmtimemake)

Preferred time scale will add a denominator to your seconds, meaning if you set 5 seconds and preferredTimeScale of 60 it will be 1/12 of a second

Comment: So you mean to say that it does the operation of just dividing the two values.

Comment: My question still remains, what should be ideal value?

Comment: I think that as long as your exposure is between the min and max exposure time, its a matter of just seeing what works best for you. You can check this explanation here: http://snapsnapsnap.photos/a-beginners-guide-for-manual-controls-in-iphone-photography-exposure/ It gives the the parameters for the best exposure and the relevant parameters for it