# Getting frames rate from CMFormatDescription

Tags: swift, objective-c, core-media

I am trying to calculate frame rate of a video format based on CMFormatDescription but I'm getting strange output that I do not know what to do with. According to the documentation, "value/timescale = seconds". This is also the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001755/trying-to-understand-cmtime-and-cmtimemake).

The code is being called while getting a video stream from FaceTime camera:

```
let av = device.activeFormat
let fd = av.formatDescription
print("time scale",fd.frameDuration.timescale)
print("value",fd.frameDuration.value)  
print("value/timescale=",fd.frameDuration.value)/Int64(fd.frameDuration.timescale))
```

This is the output:

time scale 480
value 2749654773878
value/timescale= 5728447445.579166

What am I missing? What is the frames rate?

***EDIT***: It seems that there is a bug or perhaps something is terribly wrong. time scale is always == height (of the format description). I tried it with a usb camera and they are always equal.

Comment: A frame duration of 182years seems wrong. You could instead compare consecutive frame timestamps to calculate the frame rate.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I can't I need to take it from the FormatDescription.

Comment: Where is the CMFormatDescription coming from and what os and hardware are you using?

Comment: In that example it is the active format of avcapturedevice. I am using the recent macOS. I tried to iterate over all the formats of the device and got the same result.

Comment: What do you mean by "recent macOS"? A particular version of Monterey or the beta Ventura?

Comment: Monterey 12.4 on M1.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** You don't query a device's frame rate, but you can [choose the frame rate you want](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1389290-activevideominframeduration)

The `CMTime` value you're receiving has its `flags` field set to zero.
This means it is invalid.

`CMFormatDescription`s describe several media types, and `frameDuration` is not a video property. An invalid `CMTime` result is `CMFormatDescription`'s way of saying "not found". I guess the `timescale` being the format's height is just Undefined Behaviour & I'll bet it's different on an intel mac.

This problem is easier to see in plain old C, where the sugared swift  `frameDuration` property is called `CMTimeCodeFormatDescriptionGetFrameDuration()`. Frame duration is a `TimeCode` property (whatever that is). Mixing up your format description media types does not result in compiler errors in either language.

Comment: TL;DR In some cases you do want to query possible frame rates. I did that test while developing a DAL plugin. According to the docs (CMIOHardwareStream.h), while discussing frame rates, "If no qualifier is used, the rates of the current format (as reported via kCMIOStreamPropertyFormatDescription) will be returned. If a qualifier is present, it contains the CMFormatDescriptionRef whose frame rates are desired." You are right about the CMTime having a false valid flag.

Comment: Look at `AVCaptureDeviceFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges` for supported device frame rates.